# How to make html cards align into rows and columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have found a card design which I want to use for a website at this link: https://codepen.io/virgilpana/pen/RNYQwB

When I add the html, css and js to my website, where multiple of these cards need to be aligned beside one another in rows and columns, the cards just seem to pile on top of each other. How can I edit the code to get them to align in rows and columns?

Here is the relevant code for the card:

```css
#make-3D-space {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -167px;
}

#product-front,
#product-back {
  width: 335px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

#product-back {
  display: none;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

#product-card.animate #product-back,
#product-card.animate #product-front {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

#product-card {
  width: 325px;
  height: 490px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  transition: 100ms ease-out;
}

div#product-card.flip-10 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( -10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( -10deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( -10deg);
  transform: rotateY( -10deg);
  transition: 50ms ease-out;
}

div#product-card.flip90 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 90deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 90deg);
  transform: rotateY( 90deg);
  transition: 100ms ease-in;
}

div#product-card.flip190 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 190deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 190deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 190deg);
  transform: rotateY( 190deg);
  transition: 100ms ease-out;
}

div#product-card.flip180 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transition: 150ms ease-out;
}

#product-card.animate {
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 335px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 13px 21px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  transition: 100ms ease-out;
}

.stats-container {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 386px;
  left: 0;
  width: 265px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 27px 35px 35px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

#product-card.animate .stats-container {
  top: 272px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.stats-container .product_name {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #393c45;
}

.stats-container p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #b1b1b3;
  padding: 2px 0 20px 0;
}

.stats-container .product_price {
  float: right;
  color: #48cfad;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.image_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #48daa1;
  opacity: 0;
}

#product-card.animate .image_overlay {
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.product-options {
  padding: 2px 0 0;
}

.product-options strong {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #393c45;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.product-options span {
  color: #969699;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#view_details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 112px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -85px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 172px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

#view_details:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #48cfad;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#product-card.animate #view_details {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 152px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: -75px;
  top: 115px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

div.colors div {
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}

div.colors div span {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div.colors div span:hover {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}

div.c-blue span {
  background: #6e8cd5;
}

div.c-red span {
  background: #f56060;
}

div.c-green span {
  background: #44c28d;
}

div.c-white span {
  background: #fff;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #e8e9eb;
}

div.shadow {
  width: 335px;
  height: 520px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  display: none;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<a id="view-code" href="https://codepen.io/virgilpana/pen/RNYQwB" target="_blank">VIEW CODE</a>

<div id="make-3D-space">
  <div id="product-card">
    <div id="product-front">
      <div class="shadow"></div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt.png" alt="" />
      <div class="image_overlay"></div>
      <div id="view_details">View details</div>
      <div class="stats">
        <div class="stats-container">
          <span class="product_price">$39</span>
          <span class="product_name">Adidas Originals</span>
          <p>Men's running shirt</p>

          <div class="product-options">
            <strong>SIZES</strong>
            <span>XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</span>
            <strong>COLORS</strong>
            <div class="colors">
              <div class="c-blue"><span></span></div>
              <div class="c-red"><span></span></div>
              <div class="c-white"><span></span></div>
              <div class="c-green"><span></span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> multiple of these cards need to be aligned beside one another in rows
>   and columns

I was going to write out an example of **CSS Grid**, but if you have an unknown number of cards to align in simple rows and columns, **CSS Flexbox** is the perfect tool for this sort of layout.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
background-color: rgb(63, 63, 255);
}

.card-container {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: flex-start;
max-width: 496px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 9px;
background-color: rgb(95, 95, 255);
}

.card {
width: 100px;
height: 140px;
margin: 12px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgb(63, 63, 63);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have wrapped your card into a wrapper `.card-wrapper`

```
.card-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and disable those styles from that id `#make-3D-space`

```
/*     position:absolute;    
    top:80px;
    left:50%;    
/*     margin-left:-167px; */
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Lift card and show stats on Mouseover
  $('.product-card').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('animate');
    $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').addClass('visible');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('animate');
    $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').removeClass('visible');
  });

  // Flip card to the back side
  $('.view_details').click(function() {
    $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').removeClass('visible');
    $('.product-card').addClass('flip-10');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.product-card').removeClass('flip-10').addClass('flip90').find('div.shadow').show().fadeTo(80, 1, function() {
        $('.product-front, .product-front div.shadow').hide();
      });
    }, 50);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.product-card').removeClass('flip90').addClass('flip190');
      $('.product-back').show().find('div.shadow').show().fadeTo(90, 0);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.product-card').removeClass('flip190').addClass('flip180').find('div.shadow').hide();
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.product-card').css('transition', '100ms ease-out');
          $('.cx, .cy').addClass('s1');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.cx, .cy').addClass('s2');
          }, 100);
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.cx, .cy').addClass('s3');
          }, 200);
          $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').addClass('visible');
        }, 100);
      }, 100);
    }, 150);
  });

  // Flip card back to the front side
  $('.flip-back').click(function() {

    $('.product-card').removeClass('flip180').addClass('flip190');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.product-card').removeClass('flip190').addClass('flip90');

      $('.product-back div.shadow').css('opacity', 0).fadeTo(100, 1, function() {
        $('.product-back, .product-back div.shadow').hide();
        $('.product-front, .product-front div.shadow').show();
      });
    }, 50);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.product-card').removeClass('flip90').addClass('flip-10');
      $('.product-front div.shadow').show().fadeTo(100, 0);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.product-front div.shadow').hide();
        $('.product-card').removeClass('flip-10').css('transition', '100ms ease-out');
        $('.cx, .cy').removeClass('s1 s2 s3');
      }, 100);
    }, 150);

  });


  /* ----  Image Gallery Carousel   ---- */

  var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
  var carouselSlideWidth = 335;
  var carouselWidth = 0;
  var isAnimating = false;

  // building the width of the casousel
  $('.carousel li').each(function() {
    carouselWidth += carouselSlideWidth;
  });
  $(carousel).css('width', carouselWidth);

  // Load Next Image
  $('div.carouselNext').on('click', function() {
    var currentLeft = Math.abs(parseInt($(carousel).css("left")));
    var newLeft = currentLeft + carouselSlideWidth;
    if (newLeft == carouselWidth || isAnimating === true) {
      return;
    }
    $('.carousel ul').css({
      'left': "-" + newLeft + "px",
      "transition": "300ms ease-out"
    });
    isAnimating = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      isAnimating = false;
    }, 300);
  });

  // Load Previous Image
  $('div.carouselPrev').on('click', function() {
    var currentLeft = Math.abs(parseInt($(carousel).css("left")));
    var newLeft = currentLeft - carouselSlideWidth;
    if (newLeft < 0 || isAnimating === true) {
      return;
    }
    $('.carousel ul').css({
      'left': "-" + newLeft + "px",
      "transition": "300ms ease-out"
    });
    isAnimating = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      isAnimating = false;
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Generals resets and unimportant stuff */

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: #eaebec;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.card-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#view-code {
  color: #48cfad;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 640px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

#view-code:hover {
  color: #34c29e;
}


/* --- Product Card ---- */

#make-3D-space {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 5s;
  /*     position:absolute;    
    top:80px;
    left:50%;  
/*     margin-left:-167px; */
}

.product-front,
.product-back {
  width: 335px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

.product-back {
  display: none;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.product-card.animate .product-back,
.product-card.animate .product-front {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

.product-card {
  width: 325px;
  height: 490px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  transition: 100ms ease-out;
}

div.product-card.flip-10 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( -10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( -10deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( -10deg);
  transform: rotateY( -10deg);
  transition: 50ms ease-out;
}

div.product-card.flip90 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 90deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 90deg);
  transform: rotateY( 90deg);
  transition: 100ms ease-in;
}

div.product-card.flip190 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 190deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 190deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 190deg);
  transform: rotateY( 190deg);
  transition: 100ms ease-out;
}

div.product-card.flip180 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transition: 150ms ease-out;
}

.product-card.animate {
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 335px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 13px 21px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: 100ms ease-out;
  transition: 100ms ease-out;
}

.stats-container {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 386px;
  left: 0;
  width: 265px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 27px 35px 35px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.product-card.animate .stats-container {
  top: 272px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.stats-container .product_name {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #393c45;
}

.stats-container p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #b1b1b3;
  padding: 2px 0 20px 0;
}

.stats-container .product_price {
  float: right;
  color: #48cfad;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.image_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #48daa1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.product-card.animate .image_overlay {
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.product-options {
  padding: 2px 0 0;
}

.product-options strong {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #393c45;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.product-options span {
  color: #969699;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.view_details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 112px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -85px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 172px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.view_details:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #48cfad;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-card.animate .view_details {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 152px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: -75px;
  top: 115px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

div.colors div {
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}

div.colors div span {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div.colors div span:hover {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}

div.c-blue span {
  background: #6e8cd5;
}

div.c-red span {
  background: #f56060;
}

div.c-green span {
  background: #44c28d;
}

div.c-white span {
  background: #fff;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #e8e9eb;
}

div.shadow {
  width: 335px;
  height: 520px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  display: none;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
}

.product-back div.shadow {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.flip-back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cx,
.cy {
  background: #d2d5dc;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.flip-back:hover .cx,
.flip-back:hover .cy {
  background: #979ca7;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.cx.s1,
.cy.s1 {
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

.cy.s2 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(50deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg);
  transform: rotate(50deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

.cy.s3 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

.cx.s1 {
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

.cx.s2 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(140deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(140deg);
  transform: rotate(140deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

.cx.s3 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

.carousel {
  width: 335px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.carousel li {
  width: 335px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.arrows-perspective {
  width: 335px;
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 218px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 5s;
  perspective: 335px;
}

.carouselPrev,
.carouselNext {
  width: 50px;
  height: 55px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  opacity: 0.9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carouselNext {
  top: 0;
  right: -26px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( -117deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( -117deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( -117deg);
  transform: rotateY( -117deg);
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.carouselNext.visible {
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: #efefef;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.carouselPrev {
  left: -26px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 117deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 117deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 117deg);
  transform: rotateY( 117deg);
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.carouselPrev.visible {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: #eee;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.carousel .x,
.carousel .y {
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #48cfad;
  position: absolute;
  top: 31px;
  left: 17px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.carousel .x {
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  top: 21px;
}

.carousel .carouselNext .x {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.carousel .carouselNext .y {
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="card-wrapper">
  
  <div id="make-3D-space">
    <div class="product-card">
        <div class="product-front">
         <div class="shadow"></div>
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt.png" alt="" />
            <div class="image_overlay"></div>
            <div class="view_details">View details</div>
            <div class="stats">         
                <div class="stats-container">
                    <span class="product_price">$39</span>
                    <span class="product_name">Adidas Originals</span>    
                    <p>Men's running shirt</p>                                            
                    
                    <div class="product-options">
                    <strong>SIZES</strong>
                    <span>XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</span>
                    <strong>COLORS</strong>
                    <div class="colors">
                        <div class="c-blue"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-red"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-white"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-green"><span></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
                </div>                         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-back">
         <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="carousel">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large2.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large3.png" alt="" /></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="arrows-perspective">
                    <div class="carouselPrev">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                     <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carouselNext">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                     <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flip-back">
             <div class="cy"></div>
                <div class="cx"></div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div> 
</div> 
  
  <div id="make-3D-space">
    <div class="product-card">
        <div class="product-front">
         <div class="shadow"></div>
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt.png" alt="" />
            <div class="image_overlay"></div>
            <div class="view_details">View details</div>
            <div class="stats">         
                <div class="stats-container">
                    <span class="product_price">$39</span>
                    <span class="product_name">Adidas Originals</span>    
                    <p>Men's running shirt</p>                                            
                    
                    <div class="product-options">
                    <strong>SIZES</strong>
                    <span>XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</span>
                    <strong>COLORS</strong>
                    <div class="colors">
                        <div class="c-blue"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-red"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-white"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-green"><span></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
                </div>                         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-back">
         <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="carousel">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large2.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large3.png" alt="" /></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="arrows-perspective">
                    <div class="carouselPrev">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                     <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carouselNext">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                     <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flip-back">
             <div class="cy"></div>
                <div class="cx"></div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div> 
</div> 
  
  <div id="make-3D-space">
    <div class="product-card">
        <div class="product-front">
         <div class="shadow"></div>
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt.png" alt="" />
            <div class="image_overlay"></div>
            <div class="view_details">View details</div>
            <div class="stats">         
                <div class="stats-container">
                    <span class="product_price">$39</span>
                    <span class="product_name">Adidas Originals</span>    
                    <p>Men's running shirt</p>                                            
                    
                    <div class="product-options">
                    <strong>SIZES</strong>
                    <span>XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</span>
                    <strong>COLORS</strong>
                    <div class="colors">
                        <div class="c-blue"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-red"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-white"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="c-green"><span></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
                </div>                         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-back">
         <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="carousel">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large2.png" alt="" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/245657/t-shirt-large3.png" alt="" /></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="arrows-perspective">
                    <div class="carouselPrev">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                     <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carouselNext">
                        <div class="y"></div>
                     <div class="x"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flip-back">
             <div class="cy"></div>
                <div class="cx"></div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div> 
</div> 
  
  
</div>



 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```